# Парсер на python не обходит несколько страниц на сайте, а зацикливается на одной в цикле while

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

p = 1

headers = {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}
while True:
    url = "https://global.pantum.com/product-center/p-" + str(p) + "/#content"
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    save_data = page.text
    with open("index.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        file.write(save_data)

    with open("index.html") as file:
        data = file.read()

    soup = BS(data, 'html.parser')

    is_new_hot_device = soup.find("div", class_="pro_list cf").find_all("span")
    printers = soup.find("div", class_="pro_list cf").find_all("dd")
    list(is_new_hot_device)
    list(printers)
    if len(printers):
        for i in range(0, len(printers)):
            if i >= len(is_new_hot_device):
                print(printers[i].text.strip())
            else:
                print(printers[i].text.strip() + " " + is_new_hot_device[i].text.strip().upper())
        p = +1
    else:
        break

        #print(requests.get(url, headers=headers))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Довольно типовая ошибка:

```py
p = +1
```

Здесь вы просто присваиваете в `p` единичку каждый раз.

А нужно так:

```py
p += 1
```

Comment: боже, какая глупость, спасибо, золотой человек. Не мог бы ты оценить мой код? Пишу недавно, есть ли какие-то замечения?

Comment: @ДаниилСорокин Да для начинающего вполне неплохой код. Только вы ж понимаете, что результат `list(printers)` никуда не попадает и не печатается, это бесполезная строка, как и соседняя такая же? )

Comment: почему ? в консоль выводится) но это для примера

Comment: Какая-то у вас хитрая консоль. Обычно без `print` и если это не последняя строка в интерактивном питоне, то на печать такие "висящие" строки не попадают, конечно.